# Scanner.nextInt(x) throws PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, patternsyntaxexception

i know im so nooby for asking but please i want to pass my midterm

one of the many questions i have a problem with is 
""Write an if-else statement that assigns 20 to the variable y if the variable x is greater than 100. Otherwise, it should assign 0 to the variable y."

### mine looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifelseprac1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y;
        int x=0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number for x: ");
        x=keyboard.nextInt(x);

        if (x>100)
            y=20;           
        else 
            y=0;
    }
}
```

the error code im getting is

Configuration: ifelseprac1 - JDK version 1.8.0_25

`Enter a number for x: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 525`

Comment: do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: I fail to see how the code you have pasted so far can throw this exception, since you don't use regexes at all

Comment: thanks for the speedy answers.. this is incredible.. would you guys happen to have any tips on how to complete this problem?

Comment: @Thilo what is a stacktrace

Comment: @fge: apparently `nextInt` does internally. That's the beauty of stack traces.

Comment: @Thilo argh... Good point, I didn't think `Scanner` would resort to such a mechanism!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
x = keyboard.nextInt(x);
```

Do:

```
x = keyboard.nextInt();
```

If you pass a parameter to [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)), it's interpreted as the radix of the entered integer.

I'm guessing that, for certain radices, the regex that Java generates to extract the integer is incorrect, but would need to debug the JDK to be sure.

Comment: WOW it worked!!!!thank you so much! and btw wouldnt a string need to be inserted between the parenthesis where the x was?

Comment: There's no `nextInt` method that takes a string argument.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
x = keyboard.nextInt();
```